# How do you make a shortcut for the Unwrap popup menu?

Tags: python, mesh, texturing, uv, shortcut

[image: UV Unwrap Menu]

e.g. select a cube, edit mode, Mesh menu --> UV Unwrap.. the popup that appears. I want to make a keyboard shortcut that brings up that popup menu.

- right-clicking 'UV Unwrap..' there is no "Change Shortcut" option.
- searching the User Preferences --> Input list for 'UV' or 'UV Unwrap' does not bring up the appropriate target

I suspect I can add a new shortcut under 3D View --> Mesh, but what would I type in for the keyword?

[image: new shortcut keyword]

Any ideas?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? In most cases, one could use the built-in shortcut, but in this case, the OP disabled that. This question is certainly applicable to other circumstances, and could certainly help other users who also want to make custom shortcut keys, but who may not know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

There already is a shortcut for that, pressing the <kbd>U</kbd> key in mesh edit mode.

You can find it using the *Key-Binding* search mode instead for "U". It will be under *3D View > Mesh*

Anyway that is not an operator, that is a menu so you need to use the call menu operator which is `wm.call_menu`and the menu name to use is `VIEW3D_MT_uv_map`

Comment: I had disabled the shortcut a while ago, thanks.

Do you know if there is a list of all such keywords that are possible to create shortcuts with?

Comment: No, not directly at least, as far as I know. There is the [Python API reference manual](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/) though which contains an extensive list of all operators, properties and data structures of Blender, some are mappable some are not, but all operators are there, though I'm not sure menus are listed.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Object,_Action,_Settings